# Custom Image Display with intent

Tags: android

I have an image in my local SDCard which I open using the code below. My problem is that some default options like sharing comes with the intent viewer (which i don't want). e.g. share with dropbox, bluetooth etc.

Please help....

```
void displayFile(String filepath){
       File f  = new File(filepath);
       Uri path = Uri.fromFile(f); 
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
       intent.setDataAndType(path, mimeTypeFromExtension);  
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
       startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is implicit intent, and implicit intents works with intent filters, so more specific intent you start, less choice, so, if you know activity name, can convert this intent to explicit intent, and then can start directly specific activity.

Comment: i am using the default apps , and file is an image...what else has to be done from my end..plz explain with some code

Comment: how to find the default activity to hit ?